# Associating automated tests with manual in Azure Devops

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, pytest

I need to somehow associate the automated tests with manual test plan in Azure. I already installed Visual Studio and open my automated test cases in VS. But when I am trying to click "Associate to Test Case" I got the error that functionality is applicable only with MSTest, XUNIT etc. And my framework Pytest is out of this list.

Does that mean I have no possibility to associate my automated test cases with manual one using this functionality? But maybe I can do it in other way? Maybe something can be done with yaml file? Or I can simply tagged automated test cases directly in Test Plan? Or maybe I can install third party plugin for pytest? Or maybe there is a way to build a matrix with manual/automated test cases?

I have no idea, but I need to have the visual picture of test cases matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean I have no possibility to associate my automated test
> cases with manual one using this functionality

Yes, we cannot associate framework Pytest to test case in Azure DevOps. It's not supported.

See [What types of tests are supported?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#q-what-types-of-tests-are-supported) for details.

> A: These are the limitations for each type of test:
>
> - Coded UI test, Selenium tests, and unit tests written using Version 1
>   of the MSTest framework can be associated with a test case.
> - Tests that use MSTest v2, NUnit, and xUnit frameworks can be associated with a test case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. However, these tests cannot be run using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
> - Tests that use the .NET core framework can be associated with a test case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. To run the .NET core tests the appropriate target framework must be specified in a runsettings file. However, these tests cannot be run using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
> - Tests that use other test frameworks such as Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests such as Mocha or QUnit), or Jest cannot be associated with a test case.
> - Associating generic tests may work, but running these tests is not supported.

However, you can reference the following blogs to run Python test with Azure DevOps pipeline:

- [Run Python test with Azure DevOps pipeline](https://www.codewrecks.com/post/old/2018/11/run-python-test-with-azure-devops-pipeline/)
- [Selenium Python Tests & Azure DevOps Integration – Made for each other!](https://learndevtestops.com/2021/03/14/selenium-python-tests-azure-devops-integration-made-for-each-other/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer it is partially clarified my question. What about the tags? Do we have the chance in Azure DevOps to tag some tests as automated or not, I mean build some matrix in order to clearly presenting the requirements coverage.

Comment: @Jay There isn't s straightforward way to do that in Azure DevOps. However, you can reference [Requirements traceability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/requirements-traceability?view=azure-devops) , it 
 can associate the requirements to test cases, bugs and code changes. And there's already a [suggestion ticket-Requirements traceability matrix](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-requirements-traceability-matrix/758445) submitted to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future release.